# Rails link_to user_profile_path doesn't find user.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user and profile model, and also two controllers. I can go to a page where all profiles are displayed, but if I want to view one single profile, this won't work. Here is the line in profiles - `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to 'Go to profile', user_profile_path(@user, profile) %>
```

I get an error,

> user_id is nil.

I also tried many other variations like :

```
user_profile_path(user.id, user.profile.id)
user_profile_path(@user, @profile)
user_profile_path(@profile)
user_profile_path(profile)
```

And I always get different mistakes. I have no ideas anymore. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my routes are a bit complicated, and the profiles#index actually shows all the profiles, but still having the current_user logged in, the right path is

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show user profile', user_profile_path(current_user, profile) %></td>
```

This way me as a current user can see other profiles. That was a tought one

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't make a model for `profile` if profile is just displaying attributes that belong to a `user`.

It would make sense if your user has all the attributes that will be displayed in the profile view, such as `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, ect..

Then you can have a profile controller and create a view for the users profile where you can just get the information from the user object and display it.

If you want to show all the profiles, then you would be showing a view of all the users with their attributes being displayed in another view. There is no need for a second model.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I already have the profile model and all the dependencies in my app. Deleting it would make me another week of work, as I am a beginner and it's not always easy to get things work. Maybe there is a way to get to a users' profile, without having to do everything from the beginning?

Comment: reference @iseitz answer. I would recommend to not do it like that split up, its better to learn things the right way even if it takes longer. All you need to do is run a migration, delete the profiles table and add the columns that belonged to profiles to users. In the long run its less work.

Answer (score 1):

If in your profile model there is a relation `belongs_to :user`, then you could try to set @user in the `show` method in your `profiles_controller.rb`
It would look something like:

```
@user = current_user
```

Here we are assuming that the user goes to see his/hers own profile. And this would be the best practice to avoid messing with personal data.

If we are talking about visiting random profile from the list, then you have this kind of link located near each profile that is listed on the #index page and it should par default pick the profile.id. In this case:

```
@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
@user = User.find(@profile.user_id)#This part will depend on how you relate profile and user.
```

It can also be `@user = User.find(@profile.user.id)`

Again as ricks mentioned it is true that the profile structure would be more efficient as a part of User model.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work too, I think the proble was with the Reviews Controller, I was trying to add too and the connectionas I defined in both. So, getting rid of reviews, made the routes work perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't help and I'm glad you figured it out! Good job!!!